# Backdrop doesn't cover entire screen in Angular UI Tour

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I have applied tour-step-backdrop="true". It applies to only some part of screen not entire screen.[image]

As you can see the bottom part of image is not covered. So if i wanted to cover full screen then how to do it?